# How can i search a tree set containing names that start with the letter H? if so print the names (JAVA)

Tags: java, loops, object

This is what i have so far scroll down to main and youll see //part 7 this is where i have to make a small loop contain an if statment that searchs my tree i.e Person for names beginning with h in the tree set sp1

```
import java.util.*;

public class assignment8 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //question1
        System.out.println(months.MARCH.season());
        System.out.println(months.SEPTEMBER.season());
        System.out.println("------------------");

        //question2
        TreeSet<Person> sp1 = new TreeSet<Person>(); //a set of people(person is the object)
        sp1.add(new Person("David"));
        sp1.add(new Person("Sarah"));
        sp1.add(new Person("BenDover"));
        sp1.add(new Person("Jack"));
        sp1.add(new Person("Mark"));
        System.out.println(sp1);
        TreeSet<Person> sp2 = new TreeSet<Person>(); //a set of people(person is the object)
        sp2.add(new Person("David"));
        sp2.add(new Person("Sarah"));
        sp2.add(new Person("Jess"));
        sp2.add(new Person("James"));
        sp2.add(new Person("Adam"));
        System.out.println(sp2);
        //part1
        System.out.println("Boolean:  "+sp1.containsAll(sp2));

        //part2
        TreeSet<Person> insp = new TreeSet<Person>(sp1);         
        insp.retainAll(sp2);         
        System.out.println("Intersection: " +insp); 

        //part3
        TreeSet<Person> unsp = new TreeSet<Person>(sp1);         
        unsp.addAll(sp2);         
        System.out.println("Union: " +unsp);

        //part4
        TreeSet<Person> diffsp = new TreeSet<Person>(sp1);         
        diffsp.removeAll(sp2);         
        System.out.println("Dfference in sp1 and sp2: " +diffsp);

        //part5 
        TreeSet<Person> diffsp1 = new TreeSet<Person>(sp2);         
        diffsp1.removeAll(sp1);         
        System.out.println("Dfference in sp2 and sp1: " +diffsp1);

        //part6
        System.out.print("Are diffsp & diffsp1 the same: "+diffsp.equals(diffsp1));

        //part7 
        for (Person current : sp1){ 
        if(current.charAt(0)=='m' || current.charAt(0)=='M'){
        System.out.println("Name begining with M:"+current.toString())


    }
}
//Question 1
enum Season {

      SPRING,SUMMER,AUTUMN,WINTER;

     public String toString(){
            switch(this){
            case SPRING:  
            return "Spring";
            case SUMMER:
            return "Summer";
            case AUTUMN:
            return "Autumn";
            default:
            return "WINTER";
            }
     } 
}
enum months {

    JANUARY,FEBUARY,MARCH,APRIL,MAY,JUNE,JULY,AUGUST,SEPTEMBER,OCTOBER,NOVEMBER,DECEMBER;

    public String toString(){
        switch(this){
        case JANUARY:
        return "January";
        case FEBUARY:
        return "Febuary";
        case MARCH:
        return "March";
        case APRIL:
        return "April";
        case MAY:
        return "May";
        case JUNE:
        return "June";
        case JULY:
        return "July";
        case AUGUST:
        return "August";
        case SEPTEMBER:
        return "September";
        case OCTOBER:
        return "October";
        case NOVEMBER:
        return "November";
        default:
        return "December";  
        }
    }
        public Season season(){
            int k = this.ordinal(); //gets a month and makes k == to the ordinal value of that month
            if (k == 0 || k == 10 || k ==11 )
                return Season.WINTER;
            else if (k==7 || k==8 || k==9)
                return Season.AUTUMN;
            else if (k==4 || k==5 || k==6)
                return Season.SUMMER;
            else 
                return Season.SPRING;               
        }
    }
    final class Person implements Comparable<Person>{

        private final String sName;
        Person(String n){sName = n;}
        public String name(){return sName;}
        public String toString(){return sName;}

        public boolean equals(Object ob){
            if (!(ob instanceof Person))
                return false;
            Person p = (Person)ob;
            return sName.equals(p.sName);
        }
        public int compareTo(Person p){
            return sName.compareTo(p.sName);
        }
        public int hashCode(){
            return sName.hashCode();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are aware of Java `TreeSet` doesn't have any `charAt()` method? And `charAt` method returns a `character` not a `String`.

Comment: Although If you were using `for(Person j : sp1)` then OK.

Comment: So how would i write it ? btw what i have in part 7 is garbage i was trying random stuff

Comment: @DavidDooley What exactly don't you know? How to loop through the members of a Set? (look in the API doc for Set) How to get the first character of a String? (Look into API doc for String) How to compare a char with 'H'? How to get the name of a Person?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can try adding a boolean field (flag) to the Person class indicating whether `sName` starts with h (check could be done in the constructor) and also add a getter method returning the value of the boolean variable.

So in the `foreach` loop you can use this getter method for checking the state of the object's flag.

Comment: There has to be a easier way our lecturer told us all we need to do is write like 4 lines of code in main to get a result.

Comment: -1 because this is a very bad advise. In fact, one should never store easily recomputable values.

Comment: Uhmm not sure, but declaring a variable - 1 line, getter method 1 line, and calling the method takes 1 more. So its even more compact :)

Comment: Its not recomputable, theres no setter method for the name

Comment: this is due in 15 mins help me people less arguing

Comment: The information whether the name starts with 'H' is easily computable. Tell me, how many variables of this kind will you have? Consider, the prof may ask tomorrow to find Persons whose names start with 'A', 'B' or 'Z'.

Comment: for (Person current : sp1)
        {
            if(current.name().charAt(0)=='h' || current.name().charAt(0)=='H'){
                System.out.println(current.toString());  
            }
          
          
        }

Comment: btw thats not a good looking toSting method...

Comment: -1 for spoonfeeding the code.

Comment: +1 he may have given my the code but turns out i was only missing .name() method in my statement and i fully understand what is happening .Its that the objective ? alot easier to understand than the code that is forgien to me that you sent

Answer (score 0):

Since this is an assignment I will not supply the whole code but can give you a start

```
    TreeSet<String> set = new TreeSet<>();
    set.add("Hello");
    set.add("World");
    set.add("!");

    // making an iterator for traversing each element in the set
    Iterator<String> iterator = set.iterator(); 
    // iterator will iterate till it has something to traverse
    while(iterator.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(iterator.next()); // printing the element
    }

    // creating a new String 
    String s = "hello";
    // printing the 2nd character of the String instance
    // Note : String is considered as 0 based index like array
    // so it will print 'l'
    System.out.println(s.charAt(2));
```

Comment: +1 for **not** posting the complete solution.

Comment: i dont understand what your trying to do here. You add 3 elements to a blank set okay but after that im lost we've never done anything like that?

Comment: @DavidDooley well there is always time for starting something new.

Comment: can you explain what is happening in the code?

Comment: @DavidDooley well instead of `while` loop if I wrote `for(String s : set){System.out.println(s);}` would you understand?

Comment: @tintinmj Instead of spending time criticizing others for how much code they gave you should spend more time helping the OP understand what you have done with your code.

Comment: @bcorso what i've done is not complex. Though this is very elementary, he can search in google and will get it.